# The PHP code stops after the > in the if statement

Tags: php, html, mysql, phpmyadmin

For some reason my html stops recognizing the code for php after the first and second **>**, at the point marked with the comment `code stops here`.

The meaning for this that I need to get a picture from the database and then show it on the website as a header. I am very new to PHP and HTML. I am using phpmyadmin and sublimetext. the database is called stickerdome with the table images. in images there are 3 columns: id, name, link.

This is my code:

```
<head>
<?php
//Database Connect
$connect = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
//Database Select
$db = mysql_select_db("stickerdome",$connect);
?>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
<title> StickerDome </title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">    
</head>


<body>

<div id="banner">
    <?php
    //Query
    $query1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM images WHERE id = 1");
    $num = mysql_num_rows($query1);
    if ($num > 0) // code stops here right after the >
    {
        while ($output1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($query1)) 
        {
            $src = $output1['link'];
            echo "<img src='".$src."' alt='Image1'>"; //code stops here right after the > for the second time
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        echo "No picture found.";
    }
?>
</div>
```

This is the file in total:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<?php
//Database Connect
$connect = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
//Database Select
$db = mysql_select_db("stickerdome",$connect);
?>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
<title> StickerDome </title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">    
</head>


<body>

<div id="banner">
    <?php
    //Query
    $query1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM images WHERE id = 1");
    $num = mysql_num_rows($query1);
    if ($num IS NOT NULL) 
    {
        while ($output1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($query1)) 
        {
            $src = $output1['link'];
            echo "<img src='".$src."' alt='Image1'>";
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        echo "No picture found.";
    }
?>
</div>


<div id="navigation">
<ul>
    <li> 
        <a class="first" href="index.html">StickerDome</a>
    </li>
    <li> 
        <a class="second" href="samplepack.html">Sample Pack</a>
    </li>
    <li> 
        <a class="second" href="contact.html">Contact</a>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>

<div id="pagename"><img src="Stickedomepagename.png"></div>


<div id="text">
<h1>Welcome to Stickerdome</h1>

<p class="text">Stickerdome is a website that gives you the best stickers you could ever imagine. It gives you <br>
    - the best quality for every sticker <br>
    - the best endurance that is usable outside <br>
    - the biggest assortment <br>
    <br>
    For several years stickers started to became more popular. Everyone starting    loving stickers. You can place them almost everywhere imaginable. But there is still one thing that nobody had and that is their own stickers. Yes, your own stickers! You can design your own stickers, send them to us, and we make sure that your stickers will be on your doormat within 5 days! Every design is possible, from round to square to with a border or without. You say it we make it!
    </p>

</div>

</body>

<footer>
<p class="footer"> Stickerdome 2014 | Netherlands</p>
</footer>



</html>
```

Comment: view source-> what do you see ?

Comment: If I press inspect element is see that it recognizes the > mark as ?> form <php ... ?>

Comment: @bloodyKnuckles I just mean > but I put the exclamation marks there for you to notice them a little bit better

Comment: @bloodyKnuckles I replaced the `!! > !!` with a comment to indicate the point at which the OP claims execution stops.

Comment: @Kryten. I quote the OP: *"For some reason my html stops recognizing the code for php after the first and second >. I put exclamation marks like so: !!>!! around them so you know the exact place."* but you replaced it with `if ($num > 0)`, so the rest of the people will need to know what exactly the problem is. An added note to let everyone know would help.

Comment: @Kryten Yeah thanks, that is way more effective, thanks!

Comment: @Kryten I guess the OP approves lol, disregard my last comment ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- - no, your comment is helpful. I didn't update the original text.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I am new to this so can't help it :P

Comment: @user3750085 Not a problem. See if by adding error reporting will show any special error messages: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` plus, if you're able to view your HTML source, it could help also. Maybe it's a quotes issue.

Comment: I expect I would try a `print_r($query1)` and a `print_r($num)` before that line to see what they look like.

Comment: missing ';' here:  echo "No picture found."

Comment: @RyanVincent That "shouldn't" be an issue. The last statement in PHP doesn't need a closing semi-colon, but it's always best to use them.

Comment: @fred, ah - i just put the code into the IDE and have a look. Thanks for the 'heads up'.

Comment: @RyanVincent You're welcome. *However*, this is only applicable if there is a closing `?>` tag. Otherwise it will throw a parse error. This will work `<?php echo "test"; echo "No picture found." ?>` as opposed to `<?php echo "test"; echo "No picture found."` will throw an error. The OP has the closing PHP tag.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Because I have not enough reputation I can't show you a screenshot. That would have made things clearer for you

Answer (score -1):

you could try a different method or debug your sql.
Since i see your dutch im providing you with a link to a tutorial which greatly helped me the first time i worked with sql. maybe if you follow it you can fix your problem.

http://www.phphulp.nl/php/tutorial/overig/pdo-verbinden-met-verschillende-databases/534/inleiding/1364/

Comment: link only answers are  discouraged